# Should a custom keras true positive metric always return an integer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metrics, training-data, tf.keras

I'm working with a non-standard dataset, where my `y_true` is (batch x 5 x 1), and `y_pred` is (batch x 5 x 1). A batch sample `i` is "true" if any value of `y_true[i] > 0.`, and it is predicted "true" if an `y_pred[i] >= b` where `b` is a threshold between 0 and 1.

I've defined this custom keras metric to calculate the number of true positives in a batch:

```py
def TP(threshold=0.0):

    def TP_(Y_true, Y_pred):

        Y_true = tf.where(Y_true > 0., tf.ones(tf.shape(Y_true)), tf.zeros(tf.shape(Y_true)))
        Y_pred_true = tf.where(Y_pred >= threshold, tf.ones(tf.shape(Y_pred)), tf.zeros(tf.shape(Y_pred)))

        Y_true = K.sum(Y_true, axis=1)
        Y_pred_true = K.sum(Y_pred_true, axis=1)

        Y_true = tf.where(Y_true > 0., tf.ones(tf.shape(Y_true)), tf.zeros(tf.shape(Y_true)))
        Y_pred_true = tf.where(Y_pred_true > 0., tf.ones(tf.shape(Y_pred_true)), tf.zeros(tf.shape(Y_pred_true)))

        Y = tf.math.add(Y_true, Y_pred_true)
        tp = tf.where(Y == 2, tf.ones(tf.shape(Y)), tf.zeros(tf.shape(Y)))
        tp = K.sum(tp)

        return tp

    return TP_
```

When training, I sometimes get non-integer values. Is this because keras is averaging the values from all batches?

I have similar custom metrics for true negatives, false positives, and false negatives. Should the sum of all four of these values during training be an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two part answer: Yes, the metrics are averaged over the batches. You will see the same behavior with the built-in metrics, eg `tensorflow.keras.metrics.TruePositive`, but at the end of each epoch it will be an integer.

However, you are not persisting state for your metric, so TensorFlow just takes the mean of your returned metric. Consider subclassing `tf.keras.metrics.Metric` like so:

```
class TP(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    
    def __init__(self, threshold=0.5, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.threshold = threshold
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='true_positives', initializer='zeros',
                                              dtype=tf.int32)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):

        y_true = tf.where(y_true > self.threshold,
                          tf.ones(tf.shape(y_true)),
                          tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_true)))
        y_pred_true = tf.where(y_pred >= self.threshold,
                               tf.ones(tf.shape(y_pred)),
                               tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_pred)))

        y_true = K.sum(y_true, axis=1)
        y_pred_true = K.sum(y_pred_true, axis=1)

        y_true = tf.where(y_true > self.threshold, tf.ones(tf.shape(y_true)),
                          tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_true)))
        y_pred_true = tf.where(y_pred_true > self.threshold,
                               tf.ones(tf.shape(y_pred_true)),
                               tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_pred_true)))

        Y = tf.math.add(y_true, y_pred_true)
        tp = tf.where(Y == 2, tf.ones(tf.shape(Y), dtype=tf.int32),
                      tf.zeros(tf.shape(Y), dtype=tf.int32))
        tp = K.sum(tp)
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tp)

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def get_config(self):
        return {'threshold': self.threshold}
```

Comment: This worked great, but unfortunately I was unable to reload the model after having saved it. I had saved my original metrics as custom objects, and tried to do the same here, but tensorflow didn't like it. Maybe because it's a class and not a function?

Comment: "tensorflow didn't like it" is very vague and you should probably make a new question, but I would try loading the model like so: `tf.keras.models.load(model_path, custom_objects={'TP': TP)`. I also updated the answer to have a `get_config` method since we want to use the same the threshold after restoring the metric.

Comment: Granted that was very vague. I haven't had enough time to spend on this. I'm dealing with a lot of other custom object so I can probably work this out on my own. I just wanted to make sure you were able to reload a model using this metric.

Comment: Hi, wanted to follow up that I was able to use this metric format and reload the predictor. I think it was the `get_config` method that made the difference. Thanks!